# In jQuery UI how to add the ui close button to a draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

This is working using .sortable:

```
if ($(ui.item).find('.removeButton').length == 0){
    var removeButton = $('<span class="removeButton">X</span>').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $(this).each(function(){
            $(this).appendTo($(this).attr('parentClass'));
        });
    });
    $(ui.item).append(removeButton);
};
```

But I can't get it to work on .draggable at all. I can no longer use .sortable as the programmer made the entire thing using .draggable instead so I have to convert it some how. It seems like a pretty straightforward bit of code so I don't know why it isn't working.

The HTML is similar to a sortable with two areas, drag one side to the other.

```
<div id="source">
    <div id="su1">
      <h3></h3>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
<div id="destination">
    <div id="su1">
      <h3></h3>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

[The working .sortable.](http://jsfiddle.net/rvAgL/2/)

Comment: I copied and pasted so the su1 are dynamically generated ids and they are different on the actual document. But those inner divs (su1) are the .draggable elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off also using classes for dragging your divs, like this:

```
<div id="source">
    <div id="su1" class="source ui-state-default">
      <h3>Item 1</h3>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="su2" class="source ui-state-default">
      <h3>Item 2</h3>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    ...
</div> 
<div id="destination"> 
    <div id="su1" class="dest ui-state-highlight">
      <h3>Ìtem 1</h3>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="su2" class="dest ui-state-highlight">
      <h3>Ìtem 2</h3>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    ....
</div>​
```

Then you can create something like the following. Note that I have *not* replicated `sortable` functionality using `draggable`. This would be quite a bit of work to replicate so I leave it to you and the "programmer". This is just to demonstrate how to add the remove button and then move it back to the `source` div:

```
    $('.source').draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
    $('.dest').draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
    $('#destination').droppable({
        drop:function(ev, ui){
            var widget = $(this);
            if ($(ui.draggable).find(".removeButton").length == 0)
            {
                var removeButton = $("<span class='removeButton'>X</span>").click(function(){
                    var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
                    $(this).remove();
                    parentDiv.appendTo($('#source'))
                     $('#source div').appendTo($('#source'));
                });
                $('h3',ui.draggable).append(removeButton);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually, I was being stupid. My $(this) selectors were wrong and not targeting the correct "this."